# Error 800A0401 when i try to execute bat from vbs

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Dim strCurDir

strCurDir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory

WshShell.Run  strCurDir & "\Advertise.bat", 0, True
Wscript.Sleep(2)

WshShell.Run strCurDir &  "\Uninstall.bat", 0, True
Wscript.Sleep(2)

WshShell.Run strCurDir "\Install.bat", 0, True


Set WshShell = Nothing
Wscript.quit
```

I'm trying to execute this script in command line. I'm getting

> Error 800A0401-Expected end of statement. Source: Microsoft VBScript
>   Compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

```
WshShell.Run strCurDir "\Install.bat", 0, True
```

==>

```
WshShell.Run strCurDir & "\Install.bat", 0, True
```

Next time publish the error line number.